# Optional clauses in WHERE SQL COBOL

Tags: sql, db2, cobol

I have a form and each field is optional.
I would like to make an SQL query that includes optional conditions in the WHERE.

I'm using as a programming language COBOL, so i can't concatinate where clauses on the query

Bellow is my Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE Field1 = :VAL1
AND Field2 = :VAL2
```

How can i fill VAL1 and VAL2 when fields of the form is empty to get all row of the table `TABLE`

Comment: By "optional" do you mean those fields take the value of 1) an empty string 2) full char-spaces, or 3) null?

Comment: @TheImpaler an empty string. By the way, i can determine the value sent by the form and fill the field by any value.

Comment: This question has an answer which seems to ... answer the question stated. Please comment on it if there is something missing / otherwise mark as answer.
For the separate question on dynamic sql you may want to create a new question, specifying exactly which DBMS (some DB2) and SQL precompiler you use (the IBM one? on zOS/AIX/Linux/Windows?) and what you have tried there (possibly after inspecting its docs on that topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra condition in the filtering. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE (Field1 = :VAL1 or :VAL1 = '')
  AND (Field2 = :VAL2 or :VAL2 = '')
```

**Note**: If performance becomes an issue, it can be improved by the use of Dynamic SQL. That is, by dynamically adding only the parameters that are significant. This, of course, requires extra effort on coding and testing.

Comment: Can i construct the query by concatenating where's clauses if the form's field is not empty ? or by sending a specific value of the field when it is empty ?

Comment: @AhmedSEDDIK "Can i construct the query by concatenating where's clauses if the form's field is not empty?" -- Yes, that's exactly what Dynamic SQL is. You can do it manually by concatenating strings, or you can use an ORM solution (most ORMs do it out of the box).

Answer (score 1):

You could use different queries depending on the values filled from the form.

For example:

```
IF VAL1 EQUAL SPACES AND VAL2 EQUAL SPACES 
   EXEC SQL                                
        SELECT *                           
        FROM TABLE                         
   END-EXEC                                
ELSE IF FIELD1 EQUAL SPACES                
   EXEC SQL                                
        SELECT *                           
        FROM TABLE                         
        WHERE FIELD2 = :VAL2               
   END-EXEC                                
ELSE                                       
   EXEC SQL                                
        SELECT *                           
        FROM TABLE                         
        WHERE FIELD1 = :VAL1               
   END-EXEC                                
END-IF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLCODE =100 here is an example :

```
 EXEC SQL    
 SELECT * 
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE Field1 = :VAL1
 AND Field2 = :VAL2
 END-EXEC.

 EVALUATE SQLCODE
    WHEN ZEROS
      CONTINUE
    WHEN 100
     *fill VAL1 and VAL2 
    WHEN OTHER
     DISPLAY 'ERREUR'
END-EVALUATE.
```

Comment: Testing on the SQLCODE is done after the execution of the query, However, i want to determine the query structure in term of the content of the parameters before its execution